# How can I improve the performance of this ADO.NET connection object

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I have written a simple connection class, to read from an ODBC-compatible database.

The `SQLplusConnection` class is provided by the DB vendor, and inherits `Data.Common.DbConnection`

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports AspenTech.SQLplus
Public Class IP21Connection
    Private connection As SQLplusConnection
    Public Const SQLPlusISO8601Format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"
    Public Sub New(hostName As String)
        Dim connectionStringBuilder = New SQLplusConnectionStringBuilder With {
            .Host = hostName
        }
        connection = New SQLplusConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString)
    End Sub
    Public Function ExecuteSQLCommand(SQLCommand As SQLplusCommand) As DataSet
        Dim resultDataSet = New DataSet()
#If DEBUG Then
        Debug.WriteLine(SQLCommand.CommandText)
#End If
        Using connection
            connection.Open()
            Dim adapter = New SQLplusDataAdapter(SQLCommand.CommandText, connection)
            adapter.Fill(resultDataSet)
        End Using
        Return resultDataSet
    End Function

End Class
```

However, the performance is awful.

I have run a performance analysis to understand why, and I found out that:

- 15% of the runtime is `DbDataAdapter.Fill()`
- 65% of the runtime is `SQLplusConnection.Open()`

It is my understanding that ADO.NET does not really open a new connection everytime I call `connection.Open()`, but rather used a pool, and got the connection from it.

But given that the program spends four times as much time opening the connections to the DB than executing the actual query, I am starting to wonder if I am not missing an important point.

Could you give me any pointers to improve the performance?

Comment: You don't close your connection and aren't really using the With. Maybe you meant to use Using?

Comment: That code is never ever going to use a different connection because you are saving the connection object.  Pooling is internal and means when you ask for a `New sqlConnection` it checks for an available one from the pool.  Connections and other DB Provider objects ought to be created used and disposed in the smallest possible scope. Which *generally* makes such helper classes pointless.  As for performance there are a number of articles and tips around

Comment: @the_lotus Correct, I have edited.

Comment: @Maxime I don't think that would even work after the changes..

Comment: @the_lotus It does... Very slow, due to the connection.Open() overhead, but I get results, and so on.

Comment: If your connection open is that slow, it's your sql server or your network.  Try testing with just a normal SQLClient class, not that 3rd party library you are using.  If the Fill is slow, then it's your query or your database lacks proper indexes.

Comment: @LarsTech SQLplus is an oracle provider IIRC.  The `Using` in the edit is not going to do what they are intended to do (which is close and dispose of the connection) because you didnt use a local dbCon object.  Most articles I can recall reading on this were network and server related issues

Comment: @Plutonix Correct. After carefully reviewing the logs on the server, I have seen that as soon as connection.Close() is called, the connection is actually closed (and not pooled). That explains why connection.Open() is so long, it's actually opened every time.

Comment: Many DB Providers provide the means to control pooling thru the connection string.

Comment: (maybe it is off by default?)

Comment: Connection pooling is outside of the scope of ADO.NET.  If a particular DB engine implements connection pooling in their ADO.NET provider, that's great, but it's not dictated by ADO.NET.  Some providers will implement it (like `System.Data.SqlClient`) and some will not.  Even if a provider does implement connection pooling, that doesn't mean it will be implemented in the same way as another provider.  As mentioned by @Plutonix, it is often configurable via the connection string. You would need to consult the `AspenTech.SQLplus` documentation.

Comment: You state "...to read from an ODBC-compatible database", yet your post is using the vendor supplied provider classes.  While I doubt that it would be faster, have you tried connecting using [System.Data.Odbc Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc(v=vs.110).aspx) classes?